# Magento 2 - Customer group tier prices on Configurable products

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-group, tierprice

I'm trying to add a different price for a customer group an a variation of a configurable product, but I cannot find out how it works. This is my situation:

- I have a customer group named 'Retailer'
- I have a configurable product with a color attribute (red, green)
- I want to add a different price for Retailer customers on the green product

Is this even possible in Magento 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit page of child **product-> advanced setting->advanced pricing**

Now you can see the group price, set qty to 1 if you don't want use tier price on this product:
[image]

Comment: what if the admin changes the user group and the customer is still log in. It would change there

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible. I have added tier price on child product of configured product and price apply at cart page once quantity and customer group match with tier price condition. But alert or info or note not displaying at product view page for configure product.